# Tmux in Urxvt. Esc key behaves like Meta

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, tmux, urxvt, rxvt

In Tmux I have assigned <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> combinations (<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, etc) to switch between panes. It's working ok in most cases.

But after changing pane with one of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> combination every <kbd>Esc</kbd> press just repeats last <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> assigned command.

For instance, if I move to a pane with <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, now every <kbd>Esc</kbd> press recognized as <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, so it cycles horizontally from right to left.
Same for <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, but vertically.

I'm using <kbd>Esc</kbd> in vim like a lot.
Needless to say this weird thing makes life hard, because now it's impossible to exit insert mode in normal way.

How it goes with vim  (vim inside tmux inside urxvt):
If I open vim, start Insert mode, edit file, and exit Insert mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, everything goes fine.

But if after entering Insert mode I move to another pane and back with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> combinations, it become impossible to exit Insert mode.

It only happens in Urxvt, can't reproduce in Xterm.
It affects only <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Arrow</kbd> commands, vim-like binding for pane changing (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>, etc) not affected.

urxvt 9.22, Tmux (2.2 based I believe, it's in OpenBSD core)

I've spend hours to investigate the problem and found no solution.

I suppose it have something to do with Esc behave like Meta in urxvt, but what it means `like` in my case and how to address the problem I'm out of ideas.